# Any way to use classic Menus in Full Site Editing?

Tags: menus, full-site-editing

I use an FSE theme and as you might know the Navigation block is pretty limited. I want to implement a custom mega-menu-ish navigation for a big website. 
Is there any way to enable the Appearance->Menus in the admin dashboard while FSE theme is enabled, so that I could use a shortcode to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to enable the Appearance->Menus in the admin dashboard while FSE theme is enabled

I noticed that in some FSE themes the classic **Menus** admin page shows up under *Appearance*:

[image]

when they include a `register_nav_menus( ... )` call within the `after_setup_theme` hook to define the relevant classic menu locations.

See for example the Raft theme's setup:

https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/raft/1.0.3/inc/Core.php#L87

It's also possible to select classic menus within the **Navigation** block:

[image]

We note that the "Manage menus" link in the Navigation block is

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp_navigation
```

and it is not pointing the classic Menus admin page:

```
/wp-admin/nav-menus.php
```

Comment: Wow that worked. Just place `register_nav_menus( array( 'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'raft' ) ) );` in `functions.php` and it appeared in the sidebar.

Comment: ... and it should be possible to call classic menu within the Navigation block

Comment: I updated the answer with another screenshot @AkshayKNair

Comment: I used the code but I cannot find how to call the classic menu in the fse editor. In the navigation block it doesn't appear the option as you posted in the screenshot. could you help me finding a solution?