# How to add custom menu to block theme?

Tags: menus, block-editor, full-site-editing

I'm creating a theme based on the 2023 block theme from WordPress 6.1.

I need to create a custom menu as the built-in one is too limited for me.
I initially thought I can just enter the menu under "appearance-> menus", then output it with php somehow, but then I've noticed that appearance-> menus no longer exists.

What is the right approach for building a custom menu with block themes?

Do I just create a custom HTML block and hardcode the menu? is that the way?

Comment: Not sure what kind of changes are meant here but it is possible to use classical menus in full site editing if that helps here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/410314/26350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like old menus are just going away in FSE wordpress and a new way of doing it is through inserting a menu block.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this? Specifically I see there is a somewhat hidden menu for each block in the new Site Editor? I am also wondering, where one should define defaults?